# Possible incompatibility between varwidth and ocgcolorlinks (hyperref/ocgx2)

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, incompatibility, ocg, varwidth

In the simple example below, a reference inside `varwidth` environment fails due to `hyperref` package loaded with option `ocgcolorlinks`. Ading `ocgx2` (with the same option) makes this even worse.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage[ocgcolorlinks]{hyperref}
%\usepackage[ocgcolorlinks]{ocgx2}

\begin{document}
    \section{A section} \label{sec}

    A reference outside \texttt{varwidth}: sec.~\ref{sec}.

    \noindent
    \begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}
        A reference \hphantom{outside }\llap{inside} \texttt{varwidth}: sec.~\ref{sec}.
    \end{varwidth}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Can anybody provide a fix which would allow the usage of `ref`/`href`/`cref`/… inside `varwidth` environment without disabling `ocgcolorlinks` option of `hyperref` or `ocgx2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to locally restore \pdfliteral to the original definition (varwidth redefines it):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[ocgcolorlinks]{ocgx2}

\begin{document}
    \section{A section} \label{sec}

    A reference outside \texttt{varwidth}: sec.~\ref{sec}.

    \makeatletter
    \noindent
    \begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}
        A reference \hphantom{outside }\llap{inside}\texttt{varwidth}: sec.~\mbox{\let\pdfliteral\@@vwid@pdfliteral\ref{sec}}.
    \end{varwidth}
    \makeatother
\end{document}
```